# Using mail protocol in Codeigniter Received delay after long period

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, server, sendmail

Hi I have tried a sample mail function using codeigniter email library it returns successfull on sent email but in my gmail inbox receiving after 16 hours delayed. I dont know why it happens in my particular server. When I tried from other servers it works fine. In mail which is received after 16 hours it shows as received 16 hours ago but not actually received. Below attachment explains you and image of received headers information prepared by google apps. please guide me if any one faces already. I have too fix it soon.

Note : if this question is not related to this forum guide me where to ask.

[image]

Comment: it may have issue on your web server, contact your host service provider.

Comment: @ Niranjan N Raju MY web server is in UK when it runs evening time for uk. it runs well via cron. but when I tried in browser (it is in morning time for uk) it not works. So that i am confused whether it is web server's issue or else.

Comment: post your sample code.

Comment: $this->load->library("email");
           $config = array (
       'mailtype' => 'html',
       'charset'  => 'utf-8',
       'priority' => '1'
        );
   $this->email->initialize($config);

            
            $this->email->from('udhay@xxx.com', 'udhayavanan');  \n
            $this->email->to('xxxxxx@gmail.com'); 
            $this->email->subject('Email Test');
            $this->email->message('Testing the email class.');  
            $this->email->send();
            echo $this->email->print_debugger();

Answer (score 0):

You can try using google's smtp server instead of your server

```
$config = Array(
    'protocol' => 'smtp',
    'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
    'smtp_port' => 465,
    'smtp_user' => 'xxx', //use an email address eg: example@gmail.com
    'smtp_pass' => 'xxx', //use the password for your email address
    'mailtype'  => 'html', 
    'charset'   => 'iso-8859-1'
);
$this->load->library('email', $config);
$this->email->set_newline("\r\n");

$this->email->from($sender_email, $sender_name);
$this->email->to($data['email']);
$this->email->subject($subject);
$this->email->message($email_body);

$result = $this->email->send();
```

Hope it may help

Comment: Ya i tried with the sample mail only. ok lets i try and come back again.

Comment: Sample mail what i tried as same you said also returns success but not in sent  or receivers inbox. it comes to sent and inbox  after 16 hours as sent ago 16 hours and received 16 hours ago respectively. is it because server's over load or timezone problem.   TIA.

Comment: Timezone may cause this. not sure about that. But you mentioned about sender's sent box. If you send any email through codeigniter using gmail it will not come up on your sent box. If in case the email fails to deliver then failure notice may arrive in the sender's inbox. Anyways you can try defining timezone like this
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Singapore"); //replace with your desired city

Comment: It works in day time for india i.e now. but not works in evening time for india. Lets i try some other ways. Anyway thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

```
            $touser=$email; // email to be sent
            $subjectAdmin= "xxx";
            $headersAdmin = "From: noreply@domain.com\r\n"; 
            $headersAdmin .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
            $messageuser ='msg here'; 
            $emailSenduser = mail($touser,$subjectAdmin,$messageuser,$headersAdmin);
```

Comment: thanks for your time. i have checking with timezone.